# Call to a member function dispatch() on null in vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

I want to insert some data for the first time the module is being installed.

This is my folder structure

```
Navien/Custom
-- Setup/InstallData.php
-- Model/
   -- StateData.php
   -- StateMaster.php
   -- ResourceModel/
      -- StateMaster.php
      -- StateMaster/
         -- Collection.php
```

Here is content of my script `InstallData.php`

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;

use Navien\Custom\Model\StateData;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $eavSetupFactory;
    private $eavConfig;
    private $stateDataMaster;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig, StateData $stateData)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;    
        $this->stateDataMaster = $stateData;
    }

    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    )
    {
        $data = [
            ['code' => 'AL', 'name' => 'Alabama', 'abbreviation' => 'Ala.', 'country' => 'US'],
            ['code' => 'AK', 'name' => 'Alaska', 'abbreviation' => 'Alaska', 'country' => 'US']
        ];

        $this->stateDataMaster->insertStates($data); 
    }
}
```

`Model/StateData.php`

```
namespace Navien\Custom\Model;
use Navien\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\StateMaster;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

// class StateData extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
class StateData
{
    protected $_logger;
    protected $_stateMaster;
    protected $_objectManager;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        StateMaster $stateMaster,
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) 
    {
        // parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function insertStates($states)
    {
        if( !empty( $states ) )
        {
            $stateMasterRepository = $this->_objectManager->get('Navien\Custom\Model\StateMaster');
            $stateData = $stateMasterRepository->getCollection()->getData();
            foreach( $states as $key => $state )
            {
                if( (array_search($state['code'], array_column($stateData, 'code')) === FALSE) )
                {
                    $stateMaster = $this->_objectManager->get('Navien\Custom\Model\StateMaster');    
                    $stateMaster->setData( $state );
                    $stateMaster->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function execute()
    {

    }
}
```

`Model/StateMaster.php`

```
namespace Navien\Custom\Model;
use \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class StateMaster extends AbstractModel
{
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) 
    {
        $this->_init('Navien\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\StateMaster');
    }
}
```

`Model/ResourceModel/StateMaster.php`

```
namespace Navien\Custom\Model\ResourceModel;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class StateMaster extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('navien_states','ID');
    }
}
```

`Navien\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\StateMaster`

```
namespace Navien\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\StateMaster;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Option\Value\CollectionFactory $optionValueCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null
    ) {
        $this->_optionValueCollectionFactory = $optionValueCollectionFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct(
            $entityFactory, 
            $logger, 
            $fetchStrategy, 
            $eventManager, 
            $connection, 
            $resource
        );
        $this->logger = $logger; 
        
    }
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Navien\Custom\Model\StateMaster','Navien\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\StateMaster');
    }
}
```

Now I am getting this error

```
Error: Call to a member function dispatch() on null in /var/www/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:701 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php(412): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->beforeSave() 
#1 /var/www/dev/vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php(655): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save() 
#2 /var/www/dev/app/code/Navien/Custom/Model/StateData.php(62): Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel->save()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your constructor does not match the parent block constructor.

> Model/StateMaster.php

```
namespace Navien\Custom\Model;
use \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
```

> class StateMaster extends AbstractModel

```
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
    
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(\Navien\Custom\Model\ResourceModel\StateMaster::class);
    }
}
```